# Transposing and Aggregating DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
  name tag  time  val
0  ABC   A     1   10
0  ABC   A     1   12
1  ABC   B     1   12
1  ABC   B     1   14
2  ABC   A     2   11
3  ABC   C     2   12
4  DEF   B     3   10
5  DEF   C     3    9
6  GHI   A     4   14
7  GHI   B     4   12
8  GHI   C     5   10
```

Each row is a timestamp and shows the value between the name and tag in that row.

What I want is a dataframe where each row shows the mean value from each tag at each timestamp, like this:

```
  name  time     A     B     C
0  ABC     1  11.0  13.0   NaN
1  ABC     2  11.0   NaN  12.0
2  DEF     3   NaN  10.0   9.0
3  GHI     4  14.0  12.0   NaN
4  GHI     5   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

I can achieve this successfully by grouping by `name` and `time` and returning a transposed series each time:

```
def transpose_df(observation_df):
  ser = pd.Series()
  for tag in tags:
    ser[tag] = observation_df[observation_df['tag'] == tag]['val'].mean()
  return ser


tdf = df.groupby(['name', 'time']).apply(transpose_df).reset_index()
```

But this is slow. I feel like there must be a smarter way using a builtin transpose/reshape tool, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone see suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Option 1

Use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(values='val',index=['name','time'],columns='tag',aggfunc='mean').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
tag name  time     A     B     C
0    ABC     1  11.0  13.0   NaN
1    ABC     2  11.0   NaN  12.0
2    DEF     3   NaN  10.0   9.0
3    GHI     4  14.0  12.0   NaN
4    GHI     5   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

## Option 2:

Use `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['name','time','tag']).agg('mean')['val'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
tag name  time     A     B     C
0    ABC     1  11.0  13.0   NaN
1    ABC     2  11.0   NaN  12.0
2    DEF     3   NaN  10.0   9.0
3    GHI     4  14.0  12.0   NaN
4    GHI     5   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

## Option 3

Use `set_index` and `mean` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['name','time','tag']).mean(level=[0,1,2])['val'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
tag name  time     A     B     C
0    ABC     1  11.0  13.0   NaN
1    ABC     2  11.0   NaN  12.0
2    DEF     3   NaN  10.0   9.0
3    GHI     4  14.0  12.0   NaN
4    GHI     5   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

Comment: Yes, it helped indeed - thank you! All answers were great but I accepted yours as you provided several options.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [175]: df.pivot_table(index=['name','time'], columns='tag', values='val').reset_index()
Out[175]:
tag name  time     A     B     C
0    ABC     1  11.0  13.0   NaN
1    ABC     2  11.0   NaN  12.0
2    DEF     3   NaN  10.0   9.0
3    GHI     4  14.0  12.0   NaN
4    GHI     5   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also groupby and then unstack (equivalent to a pivot table).

```
>>> df.groupby(['name', 'time', 'tag'])['val'].mean().unstack('tag').reset_index()
tag name  time   A   B   C
0    ABC     1  11  13 NaN
1    ABC     2  11 NaN  12
2    DEF     3 NaN  10   9
3    GHI     4  14  12 NaN
4    GHI     5 NaN NaN  10
```

By the way, `transform` is for when you want to maintain the shape of your original dataframe, e.g.

```
>>> df.assign(tag_mean=df.groupby(['name', 'time', 'tag'])['val'].transform(np.mean))
  name tag  time  val  tag_mean
0  ABC   A     1   10        11
0  ABC   A     1   12        11
1  ABC   B     1   12        13
1  ABC   B     1   14        13
2  ABC   A     2   11        11
3  ABC   C     2   12        12
4  DEF   B     3   10        10
5  DEF   C     3    9         9
6  GHI   A     4   14        14
7  GHI   B     4   12        12
8  GHI   C     5   10        10
```